# DDL: SQL Question Check Constraint on multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, check-constraints

```
create table Game(

isOn boolean,

playHour int,

isOff boolean,

constraint ck_isOn_hour check ( ? )

);
```

Constraint : playHour is NULL when isOn = FALSE

Replace the '?' symbol with a valid check for the given constraint.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
constraint ck_isOn_hour check (isOn or (playHour is null and not isOn))
```

This can be simplified:

```
constraint ck_isOn_hour check (isOn or playHour is NULL)
```